# Chrome extension - adding permanently

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

We have created an extension for chrome and it works fine. The only problem is we have to add it via tools/extensions every time we start chrome.

How can the extension be loaded permanently?

Comment: Have you created an extension or just installed one? If the latter, have you looked in the Chrome control/options menu at settings - extensions? If the former I'm out of my depth.

Comment: Hi
To further explain out issue we have created an extension which we add to chrome via tools>extensions and it appears as an icon on the toolbar.
It works fine but when we close chrome down the next time we open it the extension is no longer loaded and we have to reload it again.
This is not a major issue for me but it would not be acceptable for our users.
Any ideas on how to keep the extension loaded would really be appreciated

Thanks
Richard

Comment: If you have packaged the extension, and it still dose this, try reinstalling chrome.

Comment: @PerryW, It would be better if you edited your question to add more details. Comments can get pruned.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem with an extension I use a lot that has suddenly started 'violating the Chrome Webstore Policy', so every time chrome restarts it's disabled again.
I've still not found a way to permanently enable it, but I did find another extension called 'Extensity' that makes it HUGELY easier to re-enable the disabled plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a windows domain there is a possibility that your admin might have setup some GPOs that configure Chrome extensions. I was trying to set those GPOs up for our own Extension that I built but there were some issues with how the settings would impact users with extensions they installed themselves as I recall.

Answer (score -1):

### Load the extension

Extensions that you download from the Chrome Web Store are packaged up as .crx files, which is great for distribution, but not so great for development. Recognizing this, Chrome gives you a quick way of loading up your working directory for testing. Let's do that now.

Visit chrome://extensions in your browser (or open up the Chrome menu by clicking the icon to the far right of the Omnibox: The menu's icon is three horizontal bars.. and select Extensions under the Tools menu to get to the same place).

Ensure that the Developer mode checkbox in the top right-hand corner is checked.

Click Load unpacked extension… to pop up a file-selection dialog.

Navigate to the directory in which your extension files live, and select it.

If the extension is valid, it'll be loaded up and active right away!

For further info read this [page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html).

Comment: Ok you have to create a .crx file and then dbl click it and install it

Comment: This is how you package an extension and then you can install it yourself -> http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/packaging.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply raynaya
We are able to install the extension as you describe and it works fine.
The problem we are having is if we close Chrome and re-open it the extension is no longer loaded. We want to be able to make our extension to be loaded everytime Chrome is open (like LastPass which is always loaded when we open Chrome)
Any ideas?

Rich

Comment: Did u try creating a package (.crx file) and then installing the extension ?(Check my 2nd comment) That way the problem u are mentioning should be solved.

Comment: hi Raynaya

Sorry for the delay in getting back.
We have created the .crx file and gone to tools>extensions and dragged the .crx file onto the page.
Everything goes fine - the extension is added and we get the message that its installed, but if we then close Chrome and re-open it the extension has gone again.
Is there a setting in the extension manifest that would keep the extension installed?
Once again, thanks for your help, it's really appreciated.

Comment: I am clueless :-/